# How can I use a JSR-203 file system provider with Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

We'd like to use the HDFS NIO.2 file system provider in a spark job. However, we've run into the classpath issues with file system providers: they have to be in  the system classpath to be used through the `Paths.get(URI)` API. As a result, the provider is not found even when it is provided in the jar files supplied to spark-submit.

Here's the spark-submit command:

```
spark-submit --master local["*"] \
  --jars target/dependency/jimfs-1.1.jar,target/dependency/guava-16.0.1.jar \
 --class com.basistech.tc.SparkFsTc \
 target/spark-fs-tc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

And here's the job class, which fails with 'file system not found.'

```
public final class SparkFsTc {
private SparkFsTc() {
    //
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("File System Test Case");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    JavaRDD<String> logData = sc.parallelize(Collections.singletonList("foo"));
    System.out.println(logData.getNumPartitions());
    logData.mapPartitions(itr -> {
        FileSystem fs = Jimfs.newFileSystem();
        Path path = fs.getPath("/root");
        URI uri = path.toUri();
        Paths.get(uri); // expect this to go splat.
        return null;
    }).collect();
}
}
```

Is there some mechanism to persuade spark to add the FS provider to the appropriate classpath?

Readers should note that file system providers are *special*. If you read the code in the JRE, you will see

```
ServiceLoader<FileSystemProvider> sl = ServiceLoader
        .load(FileSystemProvider.class, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()).
```

They have to be in 'the system class loader'. They are not found locally.

This thing would work fine if I acquired the `FileSystem` object reference myself instead of using `Paths.get(URI)`.

Comment: If you are using maven, you need to assembly and create an uber-jar. Did you do that ?

Comment: No, I just added the extra jars as '--jars' as per the command line. How would an uber-jar do anything different?

Comment: With the uber-jar, the dependency will be looked for inside your assembly. You won't be needed that in spark 2+

Comment: See edit. That's not true for the particular case of FileSystemProviders.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find a way forward?